# CMake FetchContent Host key verification fails when configuring with a preset containing a toolchain file

Tags: cmake

I have a c++ Library (B) that depends on another c++ Library (A). Both libraries can be cross compiled to either x86 (using msvc or mingw) or arm (using xilinx compilers via a toolchain file).
In B's top level CMakeLists.txt I have

```
include( FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
   A
   GIT_REPOSITORY ssh://git@url/A.git
   GIT_TAG        v1.0.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable( A )
```

I created CMakePresets.json with preset definitions for mingw-debug and cortexa9-debug.
The cortexa9-debug preset defines the cacheVariable CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE to be cortexa9.cmake.

When I execute `cmake --preset mingw-debug --debug-output`, A is cloned and built without error.

When I execute `cmake --preset cortexa9-debug --debug-output`, I receive the following error:

```
Cloning into 'A-src'...
Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Since the mingw-debug preset works, I verify that the ssh url is correct and I have the appropriate ssh keys to access the repository.

Are there settings related to FetchContent that I need to set in the toolchain file?

cortexa9.cmake:

```
set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} )
set( CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY" CACHE STRING "" FORCE )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE )
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux ) 
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${Path_To_Xilinx_C_Compiler} )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${Path_To_Xilinx_Cxx_Compiler} )
set( CMAKE_LINKER_COMPILER ${Path_To_Xilinx_Linker} )
set( CMAKE_AR ${Path_To_Xilinx_Archiver} )
set( CMAKE_SYSROOT ${Path_To_Xilinx_Root} )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${Path_To_Xilinx_Root} )
set( CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_PATH FALSE )
set( CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE )
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "" )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH $"" )
set( CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${Path_To_Xilinx_Includes} )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER )
set( CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> -r -v <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>" )
set( CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> -r -v <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>" )
set( CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <LINK_FLAGS> -o <TARGET>.elf <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> ${Xilinx_Link_Options} )
set( CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE 1 )
set( CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE 1 )
set( CMAKE_ASM_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE 1 )
set( CMAKE_RANLIB echo )
```